# Predicting test data with fewer features than training set

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am using the **KNeighborsClassifier()** library from Scikit-Learn to predict football outcomes using team names.   My training data has 18 statistics of a match, such as goals and number of fouls, and for my test set I can only use 2 team names.
The problem is the number of training features must match the number of test features or else I get

`ValueError: query data dimension must match training data dimension`

How can I overcome this, while keeping my training set with past statistics and test set with only the team names?

**Code**

```
df = pd.read_csv('2013p.csv') # Training data
dftest= pd.read_csv('2014p.csv') # Test Data


X = np.array(df.drop(['FTR','BbAvH','BbAvD','BbAvA'],1)) #features
y = np.array(df['FTR']) #labels classes

Xtest = np.array(dftest.drop(['FTHG','FTAG','FTR','HTHG','HTAG','HS','AS','HST','AST','HF','AF','HC','AC','HY','AY','HR','AR','BbAvH','BbAvD','BbAvA'],1))#features

ytest = np.array(dftest['FTR']) #labels classes

clf= neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors =19)#New Classifier

clf.fit(X, y)#Fit on train data

results = clf.predict(Xtest)
```

**Data**
`HomeTeam, AwayTeam, FTHG, FTAG, FTR, HTHG, HTAG, HS, AS, HST, AST, HF, AF`
`401,      301,      2   , 3   , -1 , 1   , 1   , 5 , 7 , 3  , 5  , 2 , 4`

Comment: In this case you cannot use the classifiers. You need other utilities like statistics of each team, win percentage, etc to guide that. Show your data.

Comment: Or else you may use the data of previous rows. Like the statistics of your team can be re-used in test data. Please explain more clearly what actually are you trying to predict with examples.

Comment: I have added an example of the data, some column have been omitted for space. This will be what my classifier will learn from and be trained on, then I will use only home team and away team in predictions. Also, I need to use this classifier amongst others, like Naive Bayes and Linear Regression and Decision trees

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question and I am not an expert but I think you would need to do one of the following

1. Interpolate missing features based on other features that are present
2. Average over all possible values the missing feature might have

   - Perhaps assume a likely range for each feature and then run prediction with all possible values of the feature.
   - You do get combinatorial explosion in the number of models you have to fit. Whether you can live with that depends on how many missing features you want to handle and how long each prediction takes

Comment: Averaging was how i did it

Answer (score 0):

The shape of training set must be the same with the shape of test set, so use SelectKBest to transform it.

Comment: Using this on my training features, will remove all but the 2 most significant features?

Comment: Select K Best , if k=2 , select the 2 most informative features.

Read this : 
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.SelectKBest.html

Comment: I have used this, but would there not be some information lost? For example, I have run it right now and it has decided that there will be no draws.

Comment: It has also occurred to me that, if one of the train features are not home team or away team, testing using those features will be pointless

Comment: Yes, but that's depends on your data. You need the same shape of features.

Comment: In every training and test need the same number of features. So you have two solution, better test set or select k best

Comment: I cannot adjust my test set, because as far as football predictions go I can only ever know the teams ahead of time.
Is there any way I can attribute features to particular teams?

Comment: This is not feasible. What if the SelectKBest selects other features?

Comment: If it chooses other features my test features wouldn't help predict the outcome. Is there some way to attribute the training features to home team and away team? So we are still testing for home team and away team but have stored the behaviours of each home team and away team

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the features you have are not applicable to the problem you are trying to predict. (football matches outcome)

This is what is known as data-leakage, the leakage of information from the future into the past.

The following features are not available for matches that have not played out yet:

```
FTHG = Full Time Home Team Goals
FTAG = Full Time Away Team Goals
FTR  = Full Time Result 
HTHG = Half Time Home Team Goals
HTAG = Half Time Away Team Goals
HS   = Home Team Shots
AS   = Away Team Shots
HST  = Home Team Shots on Target
AST  = Away Team Shots on Target
HF   = Home Team Fouls Committed
AF   = Away Team Fouls Committed
```

Training a model using them would yield unrealistically good predictions. This is because the model will basically learn that when  FTHG > FTAG then the outcome is Home victory.

The problem is that the full time home goals are known only after the event has finished so you have no prediction power.

You need to rework your features to only use information that is available for an event before it actually starts.

I have developed Football prediction API which I offer for free and had to carefully select the features in order to avoid data leakage.

For example some good features would be:

- Percent of games won when playing at home vs teams similar to current adversary.
- Average goals scored in the last X games.
- Average goals conceived in the last games.

These kind of features can be known ahead of the actual event.